# xhr.responseText me está devolviendo el codigo completo del echo en la console

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

Tengo este archivo index.html:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este archivo backend.php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al momento de imprimir en el div, no imprime, y en la consola me muestra la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para la próxima, publica el código en formato texto en la medida de lo posible ;-)

Comment: No para la próxima, ¡para ahora! ;) El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta, y lee [ask]. Tampoco es necesario que pidas disculpas :) Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

he copiado el código a mano (porque has puesto imágenes) y a mi me funciona perfectamente.

Tu código copiado:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
<title>Simple ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="sendRequest()">
send ajax
</button>
<div id="title"></div>
<script>
function sendRequest(){
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET","backend.php",true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }
  xhr.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

backend.php

```
<?php
echo "hola desde php"
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tan sólo añadir que he usado un servidor web real online para probarlo.

Comment: gracias,  seguia sin funcionar, buscando opciones terminé limpiando la caché y funcionó, existe algún metodo para limpiar caché por codigo y evitar estar limpiandola manualmente?

Comment: Para trabajar rápidamente, con la consola ("Herramienta para desarrolladores") abierta, puedes usar el botón derecho del ratón sobre el botón de recarga del navegador. Te dará varias opciones, como forzar recarga o vaciar caché y recargar.

Comment: excelente, gracias